# javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found character data inside an array element while deserializing

Tags: java, web-services, bi-publisher

I'm using bi publisher webservices api to assign roles to users. The code for this is

```
SecurityService_Service sevice = new SecurityService_Service();
    SecurityService securityService = sevice.getSecurityService();
    List<String> rolesList=new ArrayList<String>();
    rolesList.add("Testers");
    securityService.assignRolesToUser("testuser3", rolesList , "weblogic", "password123");
```

After running i'm getting error.
Stack trace is :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found character data inside an array element while deserializing
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:125)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)
    at $Proxy32.removeRolesFromUser(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at $Proxy33.removeRolesFromUser(Unknown Source)
    at view.BIPSecurityInfo.main(BIPSecurityInfo.java:89)
```

Comment: will anyone help on this issue......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot assign roles to users using bi publisher web services api. For assigning users/groups to application roles we need to use OBIEE enterprise manager system management API's.